# Why is hg status reporting a deleted file as Modified after a merge when this file was deleted on the current branch?

Tags: mercurial

My repo has:

```
@  2:85bb423103fb99137985c7e218ab4d5896e1aea0:default
|  removed file a
|
| o  1:46b6b63ecf64e8f108c83af85a46fd4c89335d74:b
|/   Modified file a
|
o  0:bbf90d08b30cd007038eaf7f8d3d1215ade86005:default
   Created file a
```

Now running hg merge b, I get:

```
hg merge b
remote changed a which local deleted
use (c)hanged version or leave (d)eleted? c
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved 
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
```

Now running hg diff, I get:

```
hg diff 
diff -r 85bb423103fb a
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/a Wed Oct 09 12:18:45 2013 +0800
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+bbb
```

The behaviour I expect is to have /dev/null to compare from (the file has been deleted in hg). hg status should show:

```
hg status
? a
```

However, hg status shows:

```
hg status
M a
```

**Why Hg reporting that the file has been modified here ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your confusion.  When you're asked this question during merge

```
use (c)hanged version or leave (d)eleted?
```

It's essentially saying "local has it deleted, but the branch you're merging in made a change to it, which are entirely unreconcileable acts.  Do you want to leave it deleted locally or do you want to copy in the file as it looks in branch 'b'?"   When you answer `c` saying you want the version from `b` that is changed, mercurial puts that file in place just as it would look if you'd done `hg revert --rev b a`.

So when you do `hg diff` it's comparing the nothing you had there in revision 2 (/dev/null) with what existed in `b` and so you see everything as added.

Similarly when you do `hg status` it acts as if revision 2 had merely zeroed out the file and thus it's now modified by having all of what exists in revision `b` inserted in it

If, by way of example, you answered `d` for "deleted" then the file would still be un-added after the merge and you could do `hg revert --rev b a` and the file contents on disk would be the same as in the answering `c` case but the file would be unadded.

Comment: hg status's output seems incorrect. 

The file 'a' is -deleted- (via hg rm). That's why Hg uses /dev/null in the diff. If the file does not exist, why is hg status reporting it as Modified and not as Unknown. 

IMO, Modified status means: the previous changeset had file 'a' , it exist (not deleted) and has some content 'xxx'. Now its content is 'yyy' so it is reported as Modified.

IMO, Unknow status means: the previous changeset did not have the file 'a'. Now, it has been introduced yet the dev has not flagged it as "Added".

Comment: Remember that you are merging 2 sets of changes ( what you had, and what you're merging with ), and at least one of those sets has it as modified rather than deleted. Once you merge, neither set of changesets is considered 'more important' than the other, so there's no reason to assume it would describe the changed file in terms of the set of changes that have it deleted ( ie, call it 'unknown' ). In fact, assuming you picked (c)hanged, it seems more intuitive to describe the file in terms of the set of changesets you chose ( the ones that have it changed ).

Comment: @DavidAndreoletti you say that "File 'a' is -deleted-", but it no longer is.  Mercurial said "one guy wants this deleted and one guy wants to keep it with changes -- who is right?" and by answering `c` you said "the guy that wants to keep it".  As @kindread explains both of the heads you're merging are equal votes, they had irreconcilable differences, and you picked "the guy that still thinks it should be there", so that's what the status you see is based on.